# Error when trying to install laravel/create a laravel project on windows via composer

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I want to create a new project using Laravel.

From the documentation, I downloaded Composer using its Windows executable installer.

I have already  set the path to: C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin

**I created the vendor\bin directory

From the command prompt, the command "composer" works.
I tried to install Laravel using the laravel installer and it gives me an error also with the create-project command.
I have tried both methods even with administrative privillages but still there is an error.

Using Laravel Installer:

[ErrorException]
file_put_contents(C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin): failed to open stream: Permission denied

Using create-project method:

[InvalidArgumentException]
Composer could not find the config file: C:\Users\marti\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin
To initialize a project, please create a composer.json file as described in the https://getcomposer.org/ "Getting S
tarted" section

PLEASE HELP!

[Error when using laravel installer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUIHe.png)

[Error when using create-project method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u8pmn.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please use code snippet formatting.

Comment: I faced a very similar problem. I had my project set up in C:// drive. Later, I found that authenticated users were not given full access to folders in C: drive. I changed that in the properties and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I deleted the Composer path variable, changed directory to read "C:>" and ran the command "composer global require laravel/installer"

Answer (score 0):

Try requiring Laravel installer from composer **composer global require laravel/installer** then simply make a new laravel project **laravel new {PROJECT_NAME}**

Comment: please make sure your composer is properly installed by calling in the CMD **composer -v**

Comment: what is your composer version? and is it installed globally?

Comment: version 2.0.0-RC1, this is a new one. It's not a stable version.

Comment: OK, I see you've solved the issue, have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

Composer(for windows), as of build `v1.10.13` does not require you to manually set then **env path variable**.

> You dont have to change or add anything in the composer installation directory or to environment path variable.

If you have done so, then do the following

- Re-install composer.
- Run `composer` in a new `cmd` window, to see if its is installed properly.
- Run `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/laravel <your project name>` and now your project should be set up properly.